# Hibernate could not extract ResultSet on inherited class

Tags: java, hibernate

I got an object that inherit from another and i am trying to save (persist) it in my db. The problem is that when i try, i got this error :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I don't know what i did wrong.. Here is my classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calamar.derogation")
public class Derogation 
{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "derogation_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "derogation_seq_gen", sequenceName = "calamar.derogation_id_seq",initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="derogation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("id")
    private Set<DerogationFille> listDerogationFille;

    [...]
}

@Entity
public abstract class DerogationFille{

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected int id;

    @ManyToOne
    protected Derogation derogation;
    [...]
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "calamar.derogationlinux")
public class DerogationLinux extends DerogationFille
{

    private String chemin;
    private String userFam;
    private String serveur;
    @Column(name="typederogation")
    private String type;
    [...]
}
```

I got the error on this lines :

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

entityManager.persist(derogation);
```

### EDIT 1 ##

I haven't looked at my correctly, i've got this error into it too, i think it is the main problem

```
ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
```

Comment: is `calamar` your schema?

Comment: Yes, calamr is my schema

Comment: ok, see my answer. you have to declare your schema with `schema` property.

Answer (score 1):

Please annotate your entities like this

```
@Table(name = "derogation", schema = "calamar")
```

Comment: Ok, i've did it but the problem still remain. I've edited my firt post by the way.

Comment: `hibernate_sequence` is in general for HIbernate Envers. do you use Hibernate Envers?

Comment: you can create the sequence with sth like this `CREATE SEQUENCE calamar.hibernate_sequence START 1;`

Comment: No, i do'n't think .. I don't even know what it is. It's a basic web project in Eclipse

Comment: aaa sorry i didnt see this `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`. so it complains correctly :). create the sequence and try again

Comment: Aaaaah okay yes i think it is this ! Before it was working but i deleted it and forgot it. Before the id was specific to each classes so i had this : 
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "derogationlinux_seq_gen")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "derogationlinux_seq_gen", sequenceName = "calamar.derogationlinux_id_seq",initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
But now that the id is in the parent class i don't know how to write my sequence correctly

Comment: why use sequence for generating the id? is there a reason for using sequences?

Comment: i'm using postgres  9.3 and have annotated my generated columns with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. working fine. did you try this approach? please also accept or upvote my answer since it helped you identify the problem. thank you!

Comment: Ok thx, so when i does this i got another error: SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement and this error in my terminal ERROR: relation "derogationfille" does not exist

Comment: table doesnt exist, or you didnt declare the schema in your annotation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117115/discussion-between-apostolos-and-antoine).